# Replacing div content with JavaScript - YouTube sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, web

I try to replace “opened persistent” with “persistent” on:

```
<div id="contentContainer" class="style-scope tp-yt-app-drawer" position="left" swipe-open style="transition-duration: 0ms;" opened persistent>
```

Any help much appreciated.

So far doesn't work with the below:

```
document.getElementById('contentContainer').innerHTML = '';
var h1 = document.createElement('h1'); h1.innerHTML = “persistent; document.getElementById('contentContainer').appendChild(h1);
```

Comment: `opened` and `persistent` are attributes, not contents. You set them with `setAttribute()` and `removeAttribute()`.

Comment: Watch your quote types. You can't use "curly" quotes in code like in the second code snippet.

Comment: Adding to @Barmar, you're also missing a quote in the 2nd snippet's 2nd line.

Also, many of those attributes are non-standard (position, opened, persistent swipe-open etc).

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. I tried also this as a simpler form and doesn't work: document.getElementById(‘contentContainer’).value = ‘persistent’;

Comment: @Christian thanks for the feedback corrected these but can't make it work so far

Comment: @belodelo as Barmar said, they're attributes. You remove them like so: `document.getElementById('contentContainer').removeAttribute("opened")`. Keep in mind that `opened` and `persistent` are separate attributes (they just happened to be with empty values) - and from what I understand in your question, you want to **remove the `opened` attribute** and **keep the `persistent` attribute**.

Comment: By the way, `<div opened>` is exactly the same as `<div opened="">` - hope this clarifies things. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/vxt9b1ey/ note how `data-attr2` and `data-attr3` are both empty strings in the console, and only the missing attribute (`data-attr4`) is null.

Comment: @Christian thank you! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<html>
  <body> 
  <div id="contentContainer" class="style-scope tp-yt-app-drawer" position="left" swipe-open style="transition-duration: 0ms;" opened persistent>
    HTML
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```js
const div = document.getElementById("contentContainer");

if(div.getAttribute("opened") !== null) div.removeAttribute("opened");
if(div.getAttribute("persistent") !== null) div.removeAttribute("persistent"); // Can skip this, since persistent attribute has to be retained.

div.setAttribute("persistent", ""); // Can be skipped if the above line is skipped.

console.log(div);
```

Comment: First of all, please explain the code in the answers. Secondly, you don't need to check if the attribute exists to remove it - `removeAttribute()` handles that for you (and should be theoretically faster since it's less DOM operations).